Sum of Cauchy distributions
Consider a sum of Cauchy distributions
$$
L(x,\eta)=\frac1{\pi}\frac{\eta}{x^2+\eta^2}.
$$
centred at $x=0$ and with widths $\eta_n=n$, for $n=1,2,\ldots$. Specifically
$$
G_N(x)=\sum_{n=1}^Na_nL(x,n),
$$
where coefficients $a_n$ are determined using the following conditions:

The function $G_N$ must be normalised, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}G_N(x)dx=1$;
Asymptotically for $x\rightarrow\infty$ the function must behave as $G_N(x)=\mathcal{O}\left(x^{-2N}\right)$.

I am interested in the limiting function $G(x)=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}G_N(x)$. My calculations show that for $N>1$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2G_N(x)dx&=\frac{N}{2N-3},&G_N(0)&=\frac{2N-1}{N\pi},
\end{aligned}
$$
which means that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2G(x)dx&=\frac12,&G(0)&=\frac{2}{\pi}.
\end{aligned}
$$
This excludes the possibility that $G(x)$ is a gaussian with width $\sigma=1/2$. So what is the limiting function? What choice should be made for $\eta_n$ in order to obtain a gaussian as a limit?

How did you compute the second moment?

@Aruralreader I considered several small $N$ cases, performed calculations with Mathematica until I could identify the sequence. Thus, no special tricks, just brute force computation.

Guess: $2x / \sinh(\pi x)$.

@WimC It is very plausible. How did you arrive at this result?

The partial results are of the form $c_N/\prod_1^N(x^2 + n^2)$ for some constant $c_N$. The product reminded me of the expansion $\prod_1^{\infty}(1 + x^2/n^2) = \sinh(\pi x)/(\pi x)$.

I don't see how your calculation for the second moment is compatible with the case $N=1$

@leonbloy Thank you for pointing this out, I have added a condition to exclude this corner case.

How do you determine the coefficients $a_n$ from the two conditions you gave?

I still don't get it. Isn't it just a mixture of Cauchy rvs? If so, shouldn't the second moment be infinite?

@leonbloy: I gave some thought to this too. I think the idea is that the asymptomatic behavior constraint severely restricts the values $a_n$ can take on. These are not probabilistic mixtures since some of the coefficients will need to be negative.

@JohnBarber I expand $G_N(x)$ at infinity and equate the expansion coefficients to zero (such that the leading term is $\sim 1/x^{2N}$), plus I impose the normalisation condition. Then, I just solve the resulting linear system of equations for $a_n$.

@Aruralreader I see. But then we'd need to assert that $G_N \ge 0$

Some observations that suggest the limit distribution.  A linear combination of $N$ Cauchy distributions is of the form
$$\frac{p(x)}{\prod_{n=1}^N(x^2 + n^2)}$$
for some polynomial $p$.  The condition at infinity implies that $p$ must in fact be a constant.  Rewriting the denominator slightly leads to
$$\frac{c}{\prod_{n=1}^N(1 + x^2/n^2)}$$
for some constant $c$.  Together with the observation that $$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1 + \frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) = \frac{\sinh(\pi x)}{\pi x}$$ and the requirement that the integral over $\mathbb R$ must be one, this suggests the limit distribution $$\frac{2 x}{\sinh(\pi x)}.$$

Nailed it. I think this is practically enough to show that that's the limit distribution... if it exists. What is left it to prove that there are indeed some weights that produce it.

I'm not sure why I said that. It's  obvious that there are indeed some weights that produce it, they are given by the partial fraction expansion

And for the partial fraction expansion this can be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655968/ramanujans-partial-fraction-decomposition-of-frac1x2a2-cdotsx2an?rq=1

Not an answer, but some clarification.
Let $z=1/x$ (so we are interested in the behaviour at $z\to0$). Then, in that zone
$$ L(z,n) =\frac{n}{\pi} \frac{z^2}{1+(nz)^2}= \frac{n z^2}{\pi} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (nz)^{2k}$$
and
$$\pi\, G_N(z) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n \, z^2\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k (nz)^{2k} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{2k+2} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n ^{2k+1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k z^{2k+2} c_k $$
with $c_k = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n n ^{2k+1}$.
Because we have the condition $\sum a_n = 1$, we have $N-1$ degrees of freedom. Hence we can (at most, hopefully) attain $c_0 = c_1 = \cdots = c_{N-2}=0$, which would imply $c_{N-1}$ is the first nonzero term, so $G_N(z) \sim z^{2N} $ as we want.
The restrictions can be put in matricial form:
$$ \pmatrix{
1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 2 & 3 & \cdots & N\\
1^3 & 2^3 & 3^3 & \cdots & N^3\\
1^5 & 2^5 & 3^5 & \cdots & N^5\\
\cdots\\
1^{2N-3} & 2^{2N-3} & 3^{2N-3} & \cdots & N^{2N-3}
} 
\pmatrix{a_1\\ a_2 \\a_3 \\ \cdots \\a_N} = 
\pmatrix{1\\ 0 \\0\\ 0 \\ \cdots \\ 0}
$$
from which $a_i$ can be obtained by matrix inversion.
Numerically, for example, for $N=5$ $a= (3.0, -3.42857143, 1.92857143, -0.57143, 0.07143)$
I don't see if/how this guarantees that $G_N(x) \ge 0$, though.
But regarding

What choice should be made for $\eta_n$ in order to obtain a gaussian as a limit?

it seems from here that the restriction of letting   $G_N(x) =
O(x^{-2N}) $ does not let us any choice.

Your matrix reformulation is quite insightful. It can be shown furthermore that $a^{(N)}{1}=\frac{2 (2 N-1)}{N+1}$ and $a^{(N)}{n+1}=\frac{(n-N)(n+1)}{n(N+1+n)}a^{(N)}_n$.

By the way, I agree with your statement about the gaussian.
